# net not working in 11.04

Tags: networking

i have the following system:
amd athlon II x4 635
kingston 4gb ddr3 1333
500gb seagate sata
cm gx 450w 85+ bronze

i have win7 along with ubuntu 11.04
now the thing is 
when I installed 11.04 inside win7 via wubi(jut to try unity) the net was working fine

but when i installed ubuntu on a separate partition as dual boot option, net is not working

I asked the same question here too....so all the required terminal command results are here

> piyush@piyush-MS-7623:~$ lspci -nnk | grep -iA2 net

```
    02:00.0 Ethernet controller [0200]: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8111/8168B   PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet controller [10ec:8168] (rev 03)
    Subsystem: Micro-Star International Co., Ltd. Device [1462:7623]
    Kernel driver in use: r8168

piyush@piyush-MS-7623:~$ ifconfig -a
eth0      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 6c:62:6d:4e:86:c9  
          inet addr:172.22.1.1  Bcast:172.22.255.255  Mask:255.255.0.0
          inet6 addr: fe80::6e62:6dff:fe4e:86c9/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:7295 errors:0 dropped:24 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:498 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:1061933 (1.0 MB)  TX bytes:49348 (49.3 KB)
          Interrupt:43 Base address:0x4000 

lo        Link encap:Local Loopback  
          inet addr:127.0.0.1  Mask:255.0.0.0
          inet6 addr: ::1/128 Scope:Host
          UP LOOPBACK RUNNING  MTU:16436  Metric:1
          RX packets:392 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:392 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:0 
          RX bytes:29902 (29.9 KB)  TX bytes:29902 (29.9 KB)
```

> piyush@piyush-MS-7623:~$ lsmod

```
Module                  Size  Used by
binfmt_misc            17565  1 
snd_hda_codec_hdmi     28103  1 
snd_hda_codec_realtek   336693  1 
snd_hda_intel          33211  2 
snd_hda_codec         103804  3 snd_hda_codec_hdmi,snd_hda_codec_realtek,snd_hda_intel
snd_hwdep              13604  1 snd_hda_codec
snd_pcm                96625  3 snd_hda_codec_hdmi,snd_hda_intel,snd_hda_codec
radeon                982197  3 
snd_seq_midi           13324  0 
snd_rawmidi            30486  1 snd_seq_midi
snd_seq_midi_event     14899  1 snd_seq_midi
snd_seq                61621  2 snd_seq_midi,snd_seq_midi_event
ttm                    76664  1 radeon
ppdev                  17113  0 
snd_timer              29602  2 snd_pcm,snd_seq
snd_seq_device         14462  3 snd_seq_midi,snd_rawmidi,snd_seq
drm_kms_helper         42136  1 radeon
psmouse                73535  0 
drm                   227495  5 radeon,ttm,drm_kms_helper
edac_core              53845  0 
serio_raw              13166  0 
snd                    67382  14 snd_hda_codec_hdmi,snd_hda_codec_realtek,snd_hda_intel,snd_hda_codec,snd_hwdep,snd_pcm,snd_rawmidi,snd_seq,snd_timer,snd_seq_device
edac_mce_amd           23464  0 
k10temp                13119  0 
i2c_algo_bit           13400  1 radeon
parport_pc             36959  1 
sp5100_tco             13744  0 
soundcore              12680  1 snd
snd_page_alloc         18529  2 snd_hda_intel,snd_pcm
i2c_piix4              13303  0 
shpchp                 37297  0 
xhci_hcd               77643  0 
lp                     17825  0 
parport                46458  3 ppdev,parport_pc,lp
usbhid                 46956  0 
hid                    91020  1 usbhid
ahci                   25951  4 
pata_atiixp            13165  0 
libahci                26642  1 ahci
r8168                 194904  0 
pata_jmicron           12747  0
```

> piyush@piyush-MS-7623:~$ dmesg | grep r8

```
[    0.000000] PERCPU: Embedded 28 pages/cpu @ffff8800cfc00000 s84416 r8192 d22080 u262144
[    0.000000] pcpu-alloc: s84416 r8192 d22080 u262144 alloc=1*2097152
[    2.764724] r8168 Gigabit Ethernet driver 8.024.00-NAPI loaded
[    2.764752] r8168 0000:02:00.0: PCI INT A -> GSI 17 (level, low) -> IRQ 17
[    2.764770] r8168 0000:02:00.0: setting latency timer to 64
[    2.764825] r8168 0000:02:00.0: irq 43 for MSI/MSI-X
[    2.838401] r8168: This product is covered by one or more of the following patents: US5,307,459, US5,434,872, US5,732,094, US6,570,884, US6,115,776, and US6,327,625.
[    2.838406] r8168  Copyright (C) 2011  Realtek NIC software team <nicfae@realtek.com> 
[   11.669244] r8168: eth0: link down
[   13.221287] r8168: eth0: link up
[   13.660067] r8168: eth0: link up
```

> piyush@piyush-MS-7623:~$ route -n

```
Kernel IP routing table
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
169.254.0.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.0.0     U     1000   0        0 eth0
172.22.0.0      0.0.0.0         255.255.0.0     U     1      0        0 eth0
0.0.0.0         172.22.1.1      0.0.0.0         UG    0      0        0 eth0
```

Comment: did you get this fixed?

Comment: yup....by installing 11.10 though

Answer (score 1):

Check your IP settings in WIN7 and then go to ubuntu's "network connections" and edit your active connection by inserting the addresses there.

Comment: thanks alex
i've already set up the required settings including ip and gateway...